# How to use layout elements in Fragment Class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, fragment

Here I made a Navigation Bar in Android using Fragment.
Now I need to print my data using Fragment class and its XML file, but I am unable to get the id in a normal manner.

**Profile.java**

```
        package com.example.dhruv.dez;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Profile extends Fragment {
        @Nullable

   //Below Line Gives Error
   BackgroundTask b = new BackgroundTask(this);

    TextView t1;

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);

        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            //Below Line Gives Error
            t1=FindViewById(R.id.username);

            getActivity().setTitle("PROFILE");


        }

    }
```

**profile.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PROFILE"
        android:id="@+id/username"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**BackgroundTask.java**

```
        public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        Context ctx;

        public BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
        {
            this.ctx=ctx;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            String work = params[0];

            if (work.equals("register")) {

                String name= params[1];
                String email = params[2];
                String mobno= params[3];
                String pass = params[4];
                try {
                    String login_url = "http://myweb.in/dhruv/signup.php";
                    URL url = new URL(login_url);
                    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    huc.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStream os = huc.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                    String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&"

                            + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") +"&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("mobno", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mobno, "UTF-8") +"&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");
                    Log.w("Error", data);
                    bw.write(data);
                    bw.flush();
                    bw.close();
                    os.close();
                    InputStream is = huc.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"));
                    String respone = br.readLine();
                    Log.w("Response", respone);
                    is.close();
                    return respone;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Why can't I use Background task object in my fragment class?
May I know why is there this problem?
And Is using fragmnets in Android projects safe?
Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: This layout is in your view parameter of onViewCreated lifecycle callback .. So use view.findViewById(YOUR_ID). It should work. Or you could use getView() method in your onActivityCreated() callback as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `fragments`for initializing views and use them you should inflate fragment layout and save it inside a `View`variable just like this:

```
package com.example.dhruv.dez;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Profile extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    private TextView t1;
    private View rootView;//View variable to save fragment layout and use it to initialize views and use them
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);

        t1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        getActivity().setTitle("PROFILE");


    }

}
```

and if you need to pass context to a class like your declared `BackgroundTask` you should pass context this way:

```
BackgroundTask b = new BackgroundTask(getActivity());
```

fore  more information about `AsyncTask`in android see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) android official documentation about it

Answer (score 0):

In a fragment you must use :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
    getActivity().setTitle("PROFILE");
}
```

Comment: sir why is that so, I never used this way in normal class

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the functionality of a activity, but fragments are a whole lot different from them.
You need to find the views inside the RootView, so you would need to change the line to:

```
t1 = view.findViewById(R.id.username)
```

Also you should probably read a bit more about fragments if you are unsure how to use them.
A good starting point probably would be https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Comment: and what about BackgroundTask b = new BackgroundTask(this);

Comment: I don't know what BackgroundTask you are using, but if you want to know about doing work in another Thread i would recommend you to get to know to AsyncTasks, Loader Or Services, just google those keywords and you will probably find what you neeed

Answer (score 0):

This layout is in your view parameter of onViewCreated lifecycle callback .. So use `view.findViewById(YOUR_ID)`. 
It should work. Or you could use `getView()` method in your onActivityCreated() callback as well..

> ***Can I know why is there problem. And Is using fragmnets in android projects safe? Are there any better ways to do this?***

Yes definitely. Its actually a good practice to use fragments when you have a more manipulating UI that keep changing and the lifecycle callbacks are well formed when using fragments. Learn more about

> Fragment transactions and Fragments

[here](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/04/android-fragment-transaction.html)..

BackgroundTask is hopefully your custom class and is not expecting a fragments instance.. Check the argument of Background task, if it is looking for context pass getActivity()

Comment: what about BackgroundTask b = new BackgroundTask(this);

Comment: see my edit above... it is not looking for a fragment instance as argument.. check if the BackgroundTask constructor looks for context... if yes then just pass your activity by calling getActivity()

Comment: I don't have enough reupations

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);

    t1 = view.findViewById(R.id.username);
    //do stuff with t1 obj

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fragment class you can use inflater to attach layout as shown in below. and u can acess elements as:

```
public class BlankFragment3 extends Fragment {

public BlankFragment3() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank3, container, false);
     //element of xml file
    TextView mTxtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    mTxtTitle.setText("Helooooooo")

    return view;
}

}
```